# UX and UI in different teams

Tags: ux-designer, visual-design, structure, team

I am looking to get some advice. My company are looking to split the UX designers and UI designers up. The UX designers would be sitting in their own team while the UI designers would be sitting in the marketing team.

I am in the process of trying to prove that this is a bad move as it will destabilise the process.

The process at the movement is UX and UI work together to create great solutions for the website. My main worry is that if these were split the priorities for each team would become different, making things less consistent and longer to produce.

Please could you help with any further reasons why UX and UI should always be in the same team?

Comment: What are the main reasons for the separation? It's challenging to provide an opinion without knowing the reasons that provoked this decision

Comment: Document the process and share it with the marketing team. Demonstrate the value of UX in the process and how it will help them hit their mark and convey their message far more accurately and with far more force than without.

Answer (score 2):

[image: UX is not UI image]

I think the key is to work from images like this, or more graphical representations of the same, that show that though UI and UX are different things that UI is a natural part of UX and that without the UI people some very critical skills would be missing from the UX team (and conversely the UI team without the guidance of good research lose much of their effectiveness).

A way I like to present "What is UX" is as a pyramid- the lowest, base level being research, it then goes up through information architecture, interaction design and then visual design at the very top. Just because these top 2 stages are the most visible it doesn't make them worth placing as a team of their own, they still rest upon the less easily visible stuff at the bottom.

Also be sure to mention that an iterative process is the best way to work. If you have a seperate UX team researching and they then hand off to the UI team to actually build like the architect giving the plans to the builders...well then that leads to a very inflexiable way of working and is just asking for the two teams to blame each other if something doesn't go right. I'm sure I recall once upon a time seeing the famous cartoon of the swing which included UX.

Answer (score 1):

UI is part of UX. I often say, "***A User Interface is part of A User's Experience***". A user has an experience with a product or service. We can try to make it a good experience or better experience and that would be what a UX Designers main goal or objective is.

I also try to explain that UX consists of mainly: Discovery Research, Information Architecture, Content Strategy, Interaction & Visual Design, and Validation Research. Their is so much more to it, but breaking it down to these categories I've found helpful for non-designers to understand.

I also try to simplify as best I can: We (your company) can Manage Products - Product Management. We can Design and Develop products - Product Design & Product Development. We can Market Products - Product Marketing. If a Marketing Team has Visual Designers, those Visual Designers should be focused on Marketing efforts.

Answer (score 0):

What a challenging dilemma...It's tough to stand up for something when others are against you. I agree that the two need each other to function and design as efficiently as possible. The UX can't be successful without the UI and vice versa.  Take a look at this article-http://ux.walkme.com/ux-design-full-guide-for-newbies/, which incorporates and explains why UI is such a significant part of UX.

Good luck with everything!

Comment: Glad it was helpful!